# Display radio value in a text input

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I need to do something (I think) very simple, but I don't have knowledge in jquery, and it dœsn't work :
I want to display the value of a radio input in a text input (#selected).

In my file I have :

```
<div class="current">
    <input id="selected" name="selected" type="text" placeholder="Value1" />
    <ul id="test">
      <li><label><input type="radio" value="Value1" name="type">Value1</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" value="Value2" name="type">Value2</label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<script> 
jQuery('label').on('click', function () {
$("selected").text($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

I want to click on the label because radio have to be hidden.

I tryed many things but it never works, can anybody helps me ?
Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    $('#selected').val(this.value);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TMqc4/1/).

Because you have `label` elements associated with the `input` elements, the `change` event will still be fired (despite being hidden).

To guard against the `change` event being fired later, by being unchecked in some manner, you could amend the above to:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
    $('#selected').val(this.checked ? this.value : $('input[type="radio"][name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TMqc4/2/).

This will set the value to the changed element's value (`this.value`) if it's checked (`this.checked`), or to the value of the checked radio-input of the same `name` otherwise.

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Better to check if it is checked :D In other case, it will assign value when uncheked. As it is radio, when checking one, others are being unchecked.

Comment: Why? It won't have a value to assign if it's not checked.

Comment: It may cause problems, as uncheck event of other radios may occur later. Single radio is single "checkbox", not a group. But I may be wrong.

Comment: If this answer is 'perfect,' as you say, please consider accepting it as the answer to your question. Also, see "[how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)"

Comment: @imudo Please read the comment above and accept that answer. Continuous ignorance **will** lead to others ignoring your questions and avoid helping you

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
jQuery('label').on('click', function () {
    $("#selected").val($(this).find('input[type=radio]').val());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JXbrr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $('#selected').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing you want to be careful of is to not make your selection scope too large. If you are implementing this on a page with other inputs/radio buttons, you could accidentally grab other values in that field.  Here's what I suggest:

First, restructure your HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="current">
    <input id="selected" name="selected" type="text" placeholder="Value1" />
    <ul id="test">
        <li><input type="radio" value="Value1" id="type-value-1" name="type"><label for="type-value-1">Value1</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="Value2" id="type-value-2" name="type"><label for="type-value-2">Value2</label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Then your javascript should look like this:

```
<script> 
$('input[name="type"]').change(function(evt) {
    $('#selected').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

The issues I can see are:

- The selector should be selecting the input by their name, because this groups the radio buttons and makes sure that you are only targeting the specific group you want to work with.  You could make the selector more specific and target "[type='radio']" but that might be overkill.
- The radio input tags should specify an ID unique to the specific radio button so that they can be targeted individually, and so that you specify the for= tag in the label to make it clickable and directly associated with the radio button.